# MVC Img to Byte[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, download

My Model

```
partial class Company
{
    ... More Properties
    public HttpPostedFileBase FilePicture { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Models.Company model)
{
    if(model.FilePicture != null)
    {
        using(Stream inputStream = model.FilePicture.InputStream)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
            if(memoryStream == null)
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            }
            model.Picture = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    //EditDefault does the persisting
    return this.EditDefault(id, model);
}
```

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", currentController, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //Clicks on the Picture and the Upload butten are forwarded to the file input tag
    //readUrl sets the image as sone as the file changes
    <input id="filePicture" type="file" name="filePicture" onchange="readURL(this);">

    <button type="button" id="pictureUploadBtnPicture" onclick="$('#filePicture').click();"> Upload</button>

    //ClearImg clears the img tag and resets the file input tag
    <button type="button" id="pictureDeleteBtnPicture" onclick="clearimg(this);"> Delete</button>

    ...if Picture not null
    ...{
        <img id="PicturePicture" src="data:image/png;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(@Model.Picture.ToArray())">

        <input type="hidden" value="@System.Convert.ToBase64String(@Model.Picture.ToArray())" name="Picture"> **added** 
    ...}
    ...else ... Render empty Picture and set it per javascript

    <input type="submit" value="Safe" class="btn btn-primary">
}
```

I have a Form which contains some properties like name, city,... and a byte[] which contains the data for a picture. The upload, show and delete are working. My problem now is that when I change something and I safe the site again, the Picture Property is null in the model, that I get in the Post Action. I guess there is something not working with the mapping.

Just to be clear I want the img mapped to the byte[].

Thx in advance for any help :)

**Update:**

Thx to Matt Tabor ;)

Added a hidden input field and now I get it in the controller.

Updated the View in case somebody needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img id="Picture" name="Picture" src="data:image/png;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(@Model.Picture.ToArray())">
```

this property is not an input, when you submit this to the server it wont sumbit the image.

you would have to use something like a hidden input storing the byte array.

try adding this under your image tag

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Picture)
```